# LOAD DATA LOCAL INPUT PATH doesnt exist

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to the Spark and Scala Technology. I'm getting the following exception while trying to load a file from local file system into table using Spark.
Spark version -2.0 and Scala version - 2.11

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file.txt' INTO TABLE student")
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: LOAD DATA input path does not exist: file.txt

Comment: is the file present in the path from where spark-shell has been initialised? please try by providing the complete path of the  file .

Comment: @Sipra - are you working in "spark local mode"? do you have several executors?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to give complete path as `file:/complete path to the file`.

In above case:

```
sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:/complete path to the file.txt' INTO TABLE student")
```

~Kedar